# How could I add a new page in my octopress blog

Tags: html, blogs, octopress

I have done these:

add an "about" page for example:

1.Create the “about” page:
`rake new_page["about"]`

2:Add the link:
`<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>`

then generated....

and the "about" tag do appear; but it couldn't be clicked; the new page do not come out

why...

Answer (score 6):

Your link needs to use the root url of your site:

`<li><a href="{{ root_url }}/about">About</a></li>`

And make sure you've added your link in: `source/_includes/custom/navigation.html`

More info: [Octopress Theming & Customization](http://octopress.org/docs/theme/template/)